# How to pass a Json data from one folder to another folder in react

Tags: json, reactjs, import

I am working on a React project, where I am trying to pass jsondata from one folder to another folder but it's not working. It is showing an error like this

> ./src/Pages/Dashboard/Dashboard.js Module not found: Can't resolve
> './API/jsondata'

This is is my code

This is jsondata.js

```js
{
    user: [
        {
            'id': '1',
            'name': 'test1',
            'age': '11',
            'gender': 'male',
            'email': 'test1@gmail.com'
        },
        {
            'id': '2',
            'name': 'test2',
            'age': '12',
            'gender': 'male',
            'email': 'test2@gmail.com'
        }, {
            'id': '3',
            'name': 'test3',
            'age': '13',
            'gender': 'male',
            'email': 'test3@gmail.com'
        }, {
            'id': '4',
            'name': 'test4',
            'age': '14',
            'gender': 'male',
            'email': 'test4@gmail.com'
        }, {
            'id': '5',
            'name': 'test5',
            'age': '15',
            'gender': 'male',
            'email': 'test5@gmail.com'
        },
        {
            'id': '6',
            'name': 'test6',
            'age': '16',
            'gender': 'male',
            'email': 'test6@gmail.com'
        },
    ]
}
```

This is Dashboard.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import Jsondata from './API/jsondata'
import './Dashboard.css';

const Dashboard = () => {
    console.log(Jsondata, 'data')
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dashboard
```

Any ideas to what may be causing the problem?

Comment: What's the overall folder structure? how do you get from 'Dashboard' to 'API'?

Comment: As a `js` file, there are no exports and thus is not a module. As a JSON file (you need to rename), it is not valid JSON as "user" is not in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons:

First one you didn't exported your data from json file.

```
export const Jsondata = [
  {
        'id': '1',
        'name': 'test1',
        'age': '11',
        'gender': 'male',
        'email': 'test1@gmail.com'
    },
    {
        'id': '2',
        'name': 'test2',
        'age': '12',
        'gender': 'male',
        'email': 'test2@gmail.com'
    },
];
```

Second maybe your file path is wrong.Just double check it.Here you have given the name Jsondata but there is no such const in json file.

```
import {Jsondata} from './API/jsondata'
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the jsondata file to data.json (the file should have .json extension) and then it works. Your import can omit .json extension like this

```
import mydata from "./data";
```

Note: You don't have to export anything in data.json file

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `variable` inside `jsondata.js` file.

Like;

```
const users = [
...
];

export { users };
```

And from Dashboard.js, you can import as

```
import { users } from './API/jsondata';
```